# NetSuite - Close a Credit Memo

Tags: netsuite

I have an open unapplied credit memo from a locked posting period. I cannot void this transaction as it gives me error. How can I undo this transaction? Can I close or void it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "close" a Credit Memo.  The "Close" action is used more on non-posting transactions, such as Sales Order and Purchase Order.  Suite Answer on Voiding, Deleting, or Closing Transactions: https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9077.

The "Void" option is controlled by the "Void Transactions Using Reversing Journals" Accounting Preference.  More info: https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/78832/loc/en_US.

To Void or Delete the Credit Memo, reopen the period, make changes, then close the period.  Suite Answer on reopening a period: https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7656.

If you need to "unwind" a Credit Memo, i.e. leave the GL impact for the closed period and unwind the financial impact in the current period.  Please share more details on the specifics of your scenario.